# HTML type string parsing question!

Tags: java, html, parsing

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/map" class="more-link">look at the Google map</a>
```

Is there any parser to get the link(www.google.com/map) from the `<a>` tag?

or the best way just to write a custom one~

Answer (score 2):

jQuery, for instance:

```
var href = $('a.more-link').attr('href');
```

Comment: As the question specifies Java I belive it's not going to run in the browser.

Comment: It might be so, but the OP didn't make it explicit whether the script was supposed to be executed server-side or client-side. And when I see "java" and "html" tags together, I tend to think "someone's confusing Java with JavaScript" before I think "Tomcat" (not that I'm implying anything) :P

Comment: Well parsing was my clue together with Java, but we just have to wait for OP to clarify  :D

Comment: Agreed, let's wait for a clarification so that my answer doesn't turn out to be misleading.

Comment: Ah, judging by the fact that your answer has been accepted, we can safely assume I DID misinterpret the question :)

Comment: -1 Posting an answer is not a guessing game. The tag says Java - if you think the OP confused Java with JavaScript, you can ask him via comments. And even it that were true, you still don't know which library he's using.

Comment: I appreciate you justifying the downvote. If you believe trying to help even with incomplete, inaccurate or unclear info about the expected solution is bad, so be it. I don't share the same point of view.

Answer (score -2):

There is many 3:rd party solutions but I am not sure which exist for Java, maybe HTML agility pack exists in a version for Java.

But another solution would be to use regex

```
/<a\s+[^<]*?href\s*=\s*(?:(['"])(.+?)\1.*?|(.+?))>/
```

Fixed the regex to handle problems suggested in comments.

Looked up some real HTML parsers for Java if you find you need more than the regex aproach

http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Since `\W` matches `>`, this will match `"not_a_url"` in `"<a name=your_regex_is_broken>...<a href=..>\"not_a_url\"</div>"`.  Strangely it will not match `"<A HREF=\"http://foo.com\">"` or `"<a href=http://foo.com>"`.

Comment: In my test it matches both a href examples, but I will look att the <a name problem ;)

Comment: Now it's fixed for those cases, ofcause, there might be more examples that does not match and for 100 % result use a real HTML parser library.

Comment: Also, this requires caseinsensitive and global flags to be true

Comment: should be this "\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^'\">\\s]+))"

Comment: If it works use it :) the (?i) does not work on all regex solutions, but that is not a problem if you tested it with your. Also you only check for " not ' which occationally is used but if you always use the same source for the HTML that will not be a problem either. My first solution matched you example and the second one was fixed to handle more cases :)